# How many terms are in $\sum \alpha_1^{a_1}\alpha_2^{a_2}\cdots \alpha_r^{a_r}\alpha_{r+1}\alpha_{r+2}\cdots \alpha_s$

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-polynomials

Suppose that $\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n$ be $n$ roots of the polynomial equation $p(x)=0$ of degree $n$. I was studying on symmetric polynomial and have come accross of several problems on like $\sum \alpha_i^2, \sum \alpha_i^3\alpha_j^2$ etc in terms of the coefficients of $p(x)$. Then the following question came to mind.

Suppose we consider $\sum \alpha_1^{a_1}\alpha_2^{a_2}\cdots \alpha_r^{a_r}\alpha_{r+1}\alpha_{r+2}\cdots \alpha_s$ where $a_1, \cdots, a_r>1$ and $s\leq n$. In other words, we are considering the sum of all the terms of the above form where the first $r$ $\alpha$s are of higher power and the rest are of unit power.

My question is: how to find out how many terms will be there in this sum? Is it possible to get the answer in closed form?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to be more explicit about what terms are in the sum. For instance, should we assume $r$ is fixed? Are the $a_1,\cdots,a_r$ fixed? If they aren't, then doesn't that mean there are an infinite number of terms, or is there an upper bound for the $a_i$s? Lastly, your sum does not seem to be symmetric ... if you apply a permutation which transposes $1$ with $s$, then any monomial in that sum will turn into one in which $\alpha_s$ has exponent $>1$, unlike all of the monomials in the original sum.

Comment: @whacka I understood. Allow me to answer. (1) Yes, $r$ is fixed. $s$ is also. (2) Secondly, all $a_i$ are also fixed. Lastly, if the sum is not symmetric, well, still I don't have any problem but to have the curiosity how many terms like above will be there. Thanks

Comment: If the $a_1,\cdots,a_r$ are fixed then there is only one term, namely $\alpha_1^{a_1}\cdots\alpha_r^{a_r}\alpha_{r+1}\cdots\alpha_s$. What you mean to write is probably $\alpha_{i_1}^{a_1}\cdots\alpha_{i_r}^{a_r}\alpha_{i_{r+1}}\cdots\alpha_{i_s}$ as $(i_1,\cdots,i_s)$ ranges over all possible permutations of $(1,2,\cdots,s)$. Then the number of terms is $s!/(m_1!m_2!\cdots)$ where $m_i=\#\{j:a_j=i\}$ and we define $a_j:=1$ for $r<j\le s$.

Comment: ohh ok , so that should be the actual notion. Fine. I apologise. I didn't know. SO ya, I want to know the answer for the last case.

Comment: @whacka: Don't forget $m_0!$, where we define $a_j=0$ for $s<j\leq n$ (so $m_0=n-s$). And the numerator should correspondingly be $n!$ rather than $s!$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum you are considering is called the monomial symmetric function $m(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_r,1,\ldots,1)$. One term is determined by associating a specific exponent (possibly $0$) to each root $\alpha_i$, in such a way that each exponent is used exactly the right number of times. In other words you can consider the available exponents (again including occurrences of $0$) as $n$ letters, to be used in a word formed by rearranging them (as in Scrabble), called the multiset permutations of the multiset of letters.

The number of (distinct) multiset permutations of a given finite multiset depends only on the multiplicities $m_1,\ldots,m_k$ of the various letters that occur (not on what those letters are). It is a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)
$$
  \binom n{m_1,\ldots,m_k}
\quad\text{where $n=m_1+\cdots+m_k$.}
$$

Comment: yes, exactly @whacka

Comment: @Marc: could you add the "symmetric functions' tag?

Comment: @WouterM. I've added `symmetric-polynomials`; somewhat more to the point.